# Не происходит активация пользователя Yii2

Tags: yii2

Не происходит активация пользователя. Помогите разобраться.

поля в бд id, username, password.
siteController.php

```
<?php

    namespace app\controllers;

    use Yii;
    use yii\filters\AccessControl;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\web\Response;
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
    use app\models\LoginForm;
    use app\models\ContactForm;
    use app\models\SignupForm;
    use app\models\User;
    use yii\base\Configurable;


    class SiteController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'only' => ['logout'],
                    'rules' => [
                        [
                            'actions' => ['logout'],
                            'allow' => true,
                            'roles' => ['@'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'logout' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function actions()
        {
            return [
                'error' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
                ],
                'captcha' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                    'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
                ],
            ];
        }

        /**
         * Displays homepage.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function actionIndex()
        {
            return $this->render('index');
        }

        /**
         * Login action.
         *
         * @return Response|string
         */
        public function actionLogin()
        {
            if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }

            $model = new LoginForm();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            $model->password = '';
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * Logout action.
         *
         * @return Response
         */
        public function actionLogout()
        {
            Yii::$app->user->logout();

            return $this->goHome();
        }

        /**
         * Displays contact page.
         *
         * @return Response|string
         */
        public function actionContact()
        {
            $model = new ContactForm();
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

                return $this->refresh();
            }
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * Displays about page.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function actionAbout()
        {
            return $this->render('about');
        }




    public function actionSignup(){
     if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
     return $this->goHome();
     }
     $model = new SignupForm();
     if($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
     $user = new User();
     $user->username = $model->username;
     $user->password = \Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);
     if($user->save()){
     return $this->goHome();
     }
     }

     return $this->render('signup', compact('model'));
    }

    }
```

LoginForm.php

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php
        namespace app\models;
        use Yii;
        use yii\base\Model;
        use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
        use yii\web\IdentityInterface;


        class User extends ActiveRecord{

            public static function findIdentity($id)
        {
         return static::findOne($id);
        }

        public static function findByUsername($username)
        {
         return static::findOne($username);
        }

        public function validatePassword($password)
        {
         return \Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password);
        }



        }
```

Comment: Задебажить? Посмотреть наличие сессии и куки. Записать трейсы и посмотреть какие методы отрабатывают, какие не отрабатывают.

Comment: ошибок не выдаёт ( но и не залогинивается :(